# PHP use glob() to feed array into foreach loop with IF Then Logic

Tags: php

Right off the bat I know there are already alot of threads on here about using Glob() to feed a foreach loop.  I've read every one I can find and I still have difficulty so I though I would post my code here in the event I am missing something.

My goal: use a foreach loop to wrap HTML pages in some markup and display them on my page.  I could have just written the HTML right into my page, but I anticipate alot changes and additions in the next couple of weeks and Im worried about overlapping versions (cant use version control here.)

So far I have this script pulling in the pages and displaying them but IF logic is not triggering.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php

        $directory = 'includes/pages';
        $dirIT = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
        try {        
            // Pull in HTML files from directory    

            foreach ( $dirIT as $key => $item ) {           
                if ($item->isFile()) {

                    if ( $key == '0')
                    {
                        echo "<div class=\"one-third column alpha\">";
                        $path = $directory . "/" . $item;
                        include $path;
                        echo "</div>";
                    }

                    elseif ($key == count ( dirIT ) - '1' )
                    {
                        echo "<div class=\"one-third column omega\">";
                        $path = $directory . "/" . $item;
                        include $path;
                        echo"</div>";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                    echo "<div class=\"one-third column\">";
                    $path = $directory . "/" . $item;   
                    include $path;  
                    echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }   
        }   
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'There are no pages to display.<br />';    
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around your numbers?

Comment: Have you tried removing quotes around the numbers in if statement? Because $key will be integer, not string value

Comment: That `is` fine as long as he's not using === or !==.

Comment: Oh whoops I did just have them in there without, but I still was not having success.  Thought maybe I have to send them in as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @newfurniturey says, the problem is caused by a missing `$` on the `elseif` line.

I would like to suggest this rewrite of your code:

```
$g = glob('includes/pages/*.html');
$c = count($g);
if( $c > 0) {
    foreach ( $g as $key => $item ) {
        echo '<div class="one-third column';
        if( $key == 0) echo ' alpha';
        if( $key == $c-1) echo ' omega';
        echo '">';
        include $item;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'There are no pages to display.<br />';    
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.  Your example worked and is far more efficient that my code.

Answer (score 2):

In the following `else if` statement, you have a small typo and aren't using an actual variable:

```
elseif ($key == count ( dirIT ) - '1' )
```

`dirIT` should be `$dirIT`. Try updating to the following and see if it helps:

```
elseif ($key == (count($dirIT) - 1))
```

Side-note: Because `$dirIT` doesn't change inside your loop, you could pre-count it before entering the loop to prevent having to re-count each time. For instance, you can have:

```
$dirITCount = (count($dirIT) - 1);
foreach ( $dirIT as $key => $item ) { 
    ...
    } else if ($key == $dirITCount) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is in your `isFile()` function. Try to use simple native (http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) `is_file()` function to check if particular item is file or not.